# Supervisord running flask app calling docker app

Tags: python, flask, docker, gunicorn, supervisord

I have a flask app that calls my dockerized app using `subprocess`.

```
@app.route('/detect', methods=['POST'])
def detect_file():
    file = request.files['wireframe']
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = str(uuid.uuid4()) + getFileExtension(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],
                    filename))
    p = subprocess.Popen(["docker","run","-v","/home/ganaraj/contours/upload:/detect","-w",
            "/detect","-it","--rm","opecv3", "./prediction",
                   filename ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output, err = p.communicate()
    return jsonify(result=output.rstrip())
    return jsonify(error='Mismatch file type')
```

When I run the flask app on its own `python app.py` it works just fine. I get back a result from the dockerized app. 
When I run the flask app using gunicorn directly `gunicorn wsgi.py` it works fine too.

When I run the flask app through gunicorn and use supervisor to keep it going - the app launches - api's work normally **EXCEPT THE DOCKERIZED** part.
I am guessing this has something to do with the **permissions** of some sort but I cant figure out what exactly I need to do to solve this.

Here is my `supervisord.conf` for reference.

```
[program:cvupload]
command = /root/anaconda/envs/cvuload/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:9000 --debug --log-level debug wsgi:app
directory = /home/ganaraj/contours
user=root
```

Is there any changes I need to do to any part of this whole tool chain so that I cna get it working fine ?

Comment: When it works fine, what is the user do you use?, what is your working directory? Do you activate any virtualenv? Do you export any environment variables?

Comment: `docker` typically requires sudo Unless you give a user or group access to it without sudo. Does the user running your app have that?

Comment: @dopstar:I do activate virtual env. No environment variables are exported.

Comment: @dirn: supervisor is started with root user `user=root` - am I right ?

Comment: While `root` has permission to sudo, I'm asking if it has permission to run Docker commands without sudo.

Comment: @dirn Yeah. I do ssh into that box as root and when I directly run the docker command it works fine.